# Recharts When Using ComposedChart Bar is over YAxis

Tags: recharts

https://jsfiddle.net/9d5gc80z/

```
<ComposedChart width={600} height={400} data={data}
            margin={{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20}}>
          <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5'/>
          <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
          <YAxis />
          <Tooltip />
          <Legend />
          <Area type='monotone' dataKey='amt' fill='#8884d8' stroke='#8884d8'/>
          <Bar dataKey='pv' barSize={20} fill='#413ea0' />
          <Line type='monotone' dataKey='uv' stroke='#ff7300' />
</ComposedChart>
```

in this example first bar is over YAxis.
[image]
how to save gap between bar and YAxis?

Correct example with BarChart
https://jsfiddle.net/3z98Lqyh/

```
<BarChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
            margin={{top: 20, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Bar dataKey="pv" stackId="a" fill="#8884d8" />
       <Bar dataKey="uv" stackId="a" fill="#82ca9d" />
</BarChart>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the XAxis padding prop like this:

```
<XAxis dataKey="name" padding={{ left: 20, right: 20 }} />
```

More info here:
https://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis

Answer (score 0):

There's a special value "gap" for XAxis.padding that accomplishes this for any bar width.

```
<XAxis dataKey="name" padding="gap" />
```

More info here: https://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis